# Total runtime of machine

Tags: linux, cpu, bios, uptime

Is there any way to read total running time of a linux system from BIOS or CPU?

I've searched BIOS informations by dmidecode. But it gives release date which is not proper for my question.

Then I've checked out `/proc`. But it holds uptime values just from last reboot. Maybe, writing these uptime values for every boot could be an option.

Then I've checked `dumpe2fs`. It gives total running time of a particular hard drive. It's useless for me because hdd could be changed while my application is running.

Except these above, how can I read or calculate the total runtime of my system ? Where can I read from ?

Comment: Total running time of the CPU, the hard drive(s), or the application? Or other  components? How would you define where the identity of "the system" comes from?

Comment: I've meant total running time of CPU. Of course I'd rather read from BIOS if there's a way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This isn’t something the firmware tracks, as far as I’m aware. Even BMCs don’t measure total uptime.

This won’t help with past uptime from previous boots, but you can start recording uptimes now, by installing a tool such as [`uptimed`](https://github.com/rpodgorny/uptimed) and setting it up so that it never discards values (set `LOG_MAXIMUM_ENTRIES` to 0 in `uptimed.conf`). That will measure operating system uptime, not total CPU “on” time, but it should be close enough... Once you’ve got `uptimed` running, you can run `uprecords` to view the totals, for example

```
    up  1492 days, 02:57:18 | since                     Sat Sep  7 00:50:06 2013
  down    61 days, 08:11:24 | since                     Sat Sep  7 00:50:06 2013
   %up               96.051 | since                     Sat Sep  7 00:50:06 2013
```

As pointed out by [quixotic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/222377/quixotic), you’ll be able to get some idea of historical uptime by looking at your logs. If you’re running systemd, you can view the boots which have been logged using `journalctl --list-boots`. Log rotation means that this is likely to miss quite a lot of uptime though.

As pointed out by [JdeBP](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/5132/jdebp), `last reboot` might give you a longer list of boots with the associated uptime.

Comment: historical uptime (for the OS, not the hardware) might be estimable given appropriate logs.  `journald` might be handy here.  though power outages, hard crashes, or other unmarked system halts might muddy those waters.

Comment: Thanks @quixotic; my comment there was in relation to installing `uptimed`, which wasn’t clear. I’ve updated my answer.

Comment: Even if one is using a systemd operating system, `last reboot` should work, and present the data that are recorded in the _old_ binary logs (which scroll far less) by `systemd-update-utmp`.

Comment: @JdeBP you’d think so, but it seems to vary wildly: some of my systems show all boots going back to their installation, others only have the last boot...

Comment: @JdeBP if memory serves correctly, `last reboot` doesn't handle system crashes well. If a system is started at 07:00 and crashes or is abruptly powered off at 08:00, but is not restarted until 10:00, the actual usage (1 hour) and declared usage (3 hours) will be off by two hours. This may have changed with `systemd`, though; I don't have a server handy to test.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have problems in getting that information from the operating system, with **tuptime** you can view a complete report of the total time of the linux system, including system crashes.

For example, as default output and resume:

```
# tuptime

System startups:    8   since   08:32:29 AM 11/24/2016
System shutdowns:   3 ok   -   4 bad
System uptime:      99.99 %   -   1 year, 195 days, 5 hours, 47 minutes and 14 seconds
System downtime:    0.01 %   -   1 hour, 6 minutes and 34 seconds
System life:        1 year, 195 days, 6 hours, 53 minutes and 48 seconds

Largest uptime:     240 days, 7 hours, 38 minutes and 10 seconds   from   08:41:51 AM 02/07/2017
Shortest uptime:    18 hours, 15 minutes and 14 seconds   from   02:26:05 PM 02/06/2017
Average uptime:     70 days, 0 hours, 43 minutes and 24 seconds

Largest downtime:   45 minutes and 15 seconds   from   10:00:01 AM 03/14/2018
Shortest downtime:  5 seconds   from   02:26:00 PM 02/06/2017
Average downtime:   9 minutes and 31 seconds

Current uptime:     85 days, 4 hours, 41 minutes and 1 second   since   10:45:16 AM 03/14/2018
```

Alternatively it is possible to get a list with all historical events with the list argument, in which you have how was the shutdown event, bad (a crash) or ok (following the shutdown process):

```
# tuptime -l

Startup:  1  at  08:32:29 AM 11/24/2016
Uptime:   46 days, 16 hours, 52 minutes and 32 seconds
Shutdown: BAD  at  01:25:01 AM 01/10/2017
Downtime: 5 minutes and 10 seconds

Startup:  2  at  01:30:11 AM 01/10/2017
Uptime:   27 days, 12 hours, 55 minutes and 49 seconds
Shutdown: OK  at  02:26:00 PM 02/06/2017
Downtime: 5 seconds

Startup:  3  at  02:26:05 PM 02/06/2017
Uptime:   18 hours, 15 minutes and 14 seconds
Shutdown: OK  at  08:41:19 AM 02/07/2017
Downtime: 32 seconds

Startup:  4  at  08:41:51 AM 02/07/2017
Uptime:   240 days, 7 hours, 38 minutes and 10 seconds
Shutdown: BAD  at  05:20:01 PM 10/05/2017
Downtime: 3 minutes and 17 seconds

Startup:  5  at  05:23:18 PM 10/05/2017
Uptime:   7 days, 14 hours, 56 minutes and 43 seconds
Shutdown: BAD  at  08:20:01 AM 10/13/2017
Downtime: 11 minutes and 35 seconds

Startup:  6  at  08:31:36 AM 10/13/2017
Uptime:   25 days, 1 hour, 7 minutes and 4 seconds
Shutdown: OK  at  08:38:40 AM 11/07/2017
Downtime: 39 seconds

Startup:  7  at  08:39:19 AM 11/07/2017
Uptime:   127 days, 1 hour, 20 minutes and 42 seconds
Shutdown: BAD  at  10:00:01 AM 03/14/2018
Downtime: 45 minutes and 15 seconds

Startup:  8  at  10:45:16 AM 03/14/2018
Uptime:   85 days, 4 hours, 42 minutes and 9 seconds
```

Take into account that `last reboot` and `journalctl --list-boots` gets the information from the logs, and these logs have a max life. Instead, `tuptime` stores the information in a particular db file dedicated to it.

For installation, supossing that you use Linux, the package is available in the Debian an derivates:

```
# apt-get install tuptime
```

If not, you can get the installation script "tuptime-install.sh" from the repository:
https://github.com/rfrail3/tuptime/